# How do i navigate on different list items one by one to add class on that items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, samsung-smart-tv

i am developing a smart tv application. i am having a trouble to add navigation on the list items. List items contains

```
<div class="work">
  <img alt="" src="./images/img_title_work.png" class="title" />
  <ul>
    <li>
      <img alt="" src="./images/1_1.png" class="title" />
      <label>What is killer contents?
        <p>2012.06</p>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img alt="" src="./images/1_2.png" class="title" />
      <label>Handmade application
        <p>2012.05</p>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want whenever user press right nav button from remote a focus class is added to the next item and removed from the first. similarly if user again press right the focus class should be added to third item. and similar case with left navigation. This project is in html css js. Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried that isn't working

Comment: i didnt tried navigation because i have no idea how to do this